# OpenURI::HTTPError (420 unused):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hpricot

I have a Rails 3 application. One of the controller method is for parsing large number of Twitter search results and storing them to the database. All works fine if the number of URLs to parse is small. But once the URLs reach 1000 or more, I have the following error after a few seconds (copied from the log file):

*Address: http://search.twitter.com/search?q=+Chas%20Salon+near:%22Baltimore%22+within:15mi
Completed   in 111436ms*

OpenURI::HTTPError (420 unused):
  app/controllers/twitter_reviews_controller.rb:41:in `block in new'
  app/controllers/twitter_reviews_controller.rb:20:in`each'
  app/controllers/twitter_reviews_controller.rb:20:in `new'

I am using Hpricot to parse the Twitter search results.

The line number 41 in the above message is this:

*doc = Hpricot(open(address))*

Does anyone knows where is the problem?

Thank you very much for any help.

Cheers,
Tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being rate limited by Twitter server. read more here: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't noticed this limitation before.

Answer (score 1):

Manage your code so it should not exceed the rate limit in an hour. and look at this response code return by http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554652/HTTP-Response-Codes-and-Errors